# Avatar con la inicial del nombre con PHP

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en una función que me permite tener las iniciales del nombre y apellido, pero solo quiero tener la inicial del nombre y cada vez que toco algo lo rompo.

Este es el código:

```
function avatar_perfil_usuario($nombre){
    $name_slice = explode(' ', $nombre);
    $name_slice = array_filter($name_slice);
    $initial = '';
    $initial .= (isset($name_slice[0][0]))?strtoupper($name_slice[0][0]):'';
    $initial .= (isset($name_slice[count($name_slice)-1][0]))?strtoupper($name_slice[count($name_slice)-1][0]):'';
    return '<div class="profile-pic">'.$initial.'</div>';
}


<?php echo avatar_perfil_usuario('antonia herrera') ?>
// Resultado
AH
```

Gracias

Comment: Suena que sólo tienes que comentar la línea que tiene `count`.

Comment: Creo que te estás complicando mucho, los strings, en PHP se trabajan también como un array, por ejemplo, si tu nombre es `$name = "Antonia Herrera"` y haces un  `var_dump($name[0]);` siempre te mostrará la primera letra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

olvidate entonces de la inicial de la segunda palabra y listo.

```
function avatar_perfil_usuario( string $nombre = ''){

    $initial = '';
    if($nombre != ''){
        $name_slice = explode(' ', $nombre);
        $initial = strtoupper($name_slice[0][0]);
        return '<div class="profile-pic">'.$initial.'</div>';
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```